# How to refresh tab content after switching tabs in wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to build a WPF window that contains tabs.Is it possible to refresh a tab page's controls(e.g textboxes, datagridview) when a different tab is selected so when i go back to the previous tab, i don't want to see any data but rather the controls are refreshed. I want to achieve this using MVVM wpf

On loding the application I populate the datagrid with table data and I have two textbox through which i can select the date range. I don't know how to refresh textbox and datagrid to go the inital state on tab switch.

I tried to refresh the data using window.Interactivity dll. But no event has been trigered.

```
           <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ontabclick}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel.cs :

```
  ontabclick = new RelayCommand(o => onclick());
  public void onclick()
    { MessageBox.Show("Working correctly"); }
```

Window.xaml

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

  <TabItem Header="AuditInformation">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ontabclick}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <UniformGrid>
                <DockPanel>
                    <StackPanel Margin="1,0,0,0" Height="55" >
                    <DatePicker Focusable = "False"  SelectedDate="{Binding FromDate}" Margin="80,10,30,-10"  Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="Fromdatedatepicker"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" >
                            <DatePicker.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
                                Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy/MM/dd}}" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DatePicker.Resources>
                        </DatePicker>

                        <Label Width="69" Height="23.277" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,-10,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="From Date"/>
                        <DatePicker Focusable = "False" SelectedDate="{Binding Todate}" Margin="265,-27,30,-10" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="Todatedatepicker" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" >
                            <DatePicker.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox1" 
                                Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy/MM/dd}}" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </DatePicker.Resources>
                        </DatePicker>

                        <Label Width="60" Height="23.277" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,-23,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="To Date"/>
                        <Button  Command="{Binding dataSearch}" Margin="300,-20,30,0" Width="60" Height="23.277"  Content="Search"></Button>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,-139">
                    <StackPanel Height="350">
                        <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
                            Height="350" Width="365" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <DataGrid.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ModelClasstab}"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Isdatementioned}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ModelClasstabwithdate   }"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.Style>
                        </DataGrid>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DockPanel>
            </UniformGrid>
        </TabItem>
```

Comment: Seems like your binding isn't working at all. Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and are you using `NotifyPropertyChanged()` to update your UI?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom yes Iam using INotifyPropertyChanged for updating UI. The viewmodel implements Inotifypropertychanged and i'm using it for all my textboxes and for datagrid. But whether for tabitem click also I need to implement it. Sorry my question might be very novice I have just started to learn wpf.

Comment: For me it's not obvious what you want. Do you want to reset the data when switching the tabs? If yes: why not just reset them in the ViewModel when you switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property of `TabControl`. And in your view model you can refresh controls you want.

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    <TabItem Header="One" >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextOne}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Two" >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextTwo}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

In your view model

```
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get => _selectedIndex;
    set
    {
        _selectedIndex = value;
        if (_selectedIndex == 0)
            TextOne = string.Empty;
        else if (_selectedIndex == 1)
            TextTwo = string.Empty;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndex));
    }
}
```